# Separate the data into different columns

Tags: r

I want to separate the below data

```
{"1": 3.0, "5": 3.0}
```

and want them into four different columns as

```
1   3.0.  5    3.0
```

Comment: Ok. Now what's your question?

Comment: You have a whole JSON  file or just a simple string? If later, why would you want to convert a simple string to columns? Can you provide your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first delete all the unnecessary characters using `gsub` then read in the data with `read.table`

```
 str1 <- '{"1": 3.01, "5.2": 3.0}'
 read.table(text=gsub("[{},:]"," ",str1))
  V1   V2  V3 V4
1  1 3.01 5.2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `str_extract` to extract only the numeric elements and then with `map_df` convert it to a `tbl_df`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_extract_all(str1, "[0-9.]+") %>% 
       map_df(~as.numeric(.x) %>%
                t %>%
                as.tibble) 
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#    V1    V2    V3    V4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1.00  3.00  5.00  3.00
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '{"1": 3.0, "5": 3.0}'
```

Comment: Or just `strsplit('{"1": 3.0, "5": 3.0}', "[^0-9.]+")[[1]]`